# How to fix "Failed to fetch" error on "apt-get update" (Docker)

Tags: linux, docker, apt-get

Every time I do "apt-get update" I get the error that my vps failed to fetch "https://download.docker.com".
I tried to remove docker because I don't need it anymore but the error still shows.

How do I remove this program from being updated or how do I remove it completely?

I have already displayed all my installed packages and I tried to remove Docker completely.

This is the result of "apt-get update":

````
Ign https://download.docker.com jessie Release
Hit http://download.webmin.com sarge/contrib amd64 Packages
Err https://download.docker.com jessie/stable amd64 Packages
  HttpError404
Fetched 6,177 B in 4s (1,520 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/jessie/stable/binary-amd64/Packages  HttpError404

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."```
````

Answer (score 0):

To remove your package completely and everything related to it's name you need to execute:

```sh
sudo apt-get purge docker OR sudo apt-get remove --purge docker
```

This will remove about everything regarding the package *docker*, but not the dependencies installed with it on installation

Now, the recomended way to resolve your problem is putting your package on **hold**:

```sh
sudo apt-mark hold docker
```

Comment: What message does it print?

Comment: "apt-get purge docker" or "apt-get remove --purge docker" says, that Docker isn't even installed anymore. "Apt-get update" gived me the same result as metioned in my main question.